# Ember.js - Access global query param from child route

Tags: ember.js

I would like to access a global query param in a nested route (child route).

The localisation setting is stored in a **Global Query Param on the Application Route**:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['localSelected']
});
```

Now I would like to access that value in my App.IndexRoute

```
App.TranslateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
         params.localSelected **NOT AVAILABLE**
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a solution by setting a global variable every time the query params updates.

In the Application Controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    queryParams: ['localSelected'],
    localSelectedOberver: function(){
        App.set('localSelected', this.get('localSelected')); 
    }.observes('localSelected').on('init'),
    localSelected: "en"
});
```

And because the controller initializes to late, you also need:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(params){
            App.set('localSelected', params.localSelected)
        }
    )}
})
```

Then whenever you need to know the localisation query param value you can just go:

```
App.get('localSelected');
```

Comment: When I wrote this I wasn't using Ember Injection yet, might be a more emberish solution to this problem.